# Adobe Animate and SCORM 2004

Tags: createjs, easeljs, scorm2004

Has anyone had any experience working with Adobe Animate for creating SCORM compliant files for LMS integration? I worked with easelJS a few years ago and see that it is now used in Adobe Animate.

We are currently using Articulate Storyline but Adobe Animate looks very promising.

Thanks

Comment: Are you referring to Animate or Edge Animate?

Comment: Hi, I am referring to Adobe Animate CC 2018. I know that Adobe Captivate can do a lot out of the box but I used to do a lot of Adobe Flash development which is why I ask.

Comment: I would think to get SCORM integrated you'd have to add some external JS library to add the support.  I have one here https://github.com/cybercussion/SCOBot.  Plenty of wiki info and implementation examples.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on this few years ago. I faced few issues which i have resolved it.

1. Preload the assets in the every page instead of loading it in beginning.
2. When your converting the files for adobe animate the movieclip/graphics have the lib as namespace

> lib.movieclip1,lib.movieclip2,lib.movieclip2

we will use multiple  adobe animate files. so Dont use the same name for the movieclip. Add a prefix with scene/ page name to avoid the conflict

> scene1_movieclip1